# DevExpress XtraReports absolute value

Tags: c#, devexpress

I've got a negative value from the sum and I need the absolute  value of it. FYI the value is in a label.

Comment: Do you need a sum of absolute values or an absolute value of a sum? What do you want your result to be, if the numbers are -1, 2, -3, 4?

Comment: I need an aboslute value of a sum. In your examlpe the sum will be possitve. But if I give a negative value for the second number, -1,-2,-3,4, than my sum will be -2. So I need an abs value for this.

Comment: Please, see my anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label which is used for the sum has event [SummaryCalculated](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRLabel_SummaryCalculatedtopic).

```
private void xrLabel1_SummaryCalculated(object sender, TextFormatEventArgs e) {
  xrLabel1.Text = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(e.Value)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: I had to use e.Text to make it work:
`e.Text = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(e.Value)).ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [`Math.Abs` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns the absolute value of a specified number.

For example;

```
string s = YourLabelControl.Text;
int i;
if(Int32.TryParse(s, out i))
{
  int abs = Math.Abs(i);
}
else
{
  //Your Label value is not a valid int.
}
```

Comment: I've used the sum function for the value and then I've got the negative value. But I cannot go with the abs function once I used the sum function. In script can I use this abs function? ex.in Summery GetResult or Summery Reset

Comment: @Nemeth What you mean with `Sum` function? What is that? _But I cannot go with the abs function once I used the sum function_ Why? Could you please clarify?